# Change the font color for the web part in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-query-web-part

I have a library where we have items. My aim is to make these items as a scrolling text in the home page.

I used Content Query webpart to get this items to the home page and I added marquee tag to this, but the items in the web part font color is blue.

Can anyone help how to change this blue to red?

Here is the code of web part

```
<marquee scrolldelay="30" direction="left" scrollamount="8" style="width: 1350px; height: 396px;"><span class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-9-5"></span><span class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-9-5"></span><span class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-9-5"></span><span class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-9-5"></span><span class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-9-5"></span>
  <p></p>
       <span class="ms-rteBackColor-2 ms-rteFontSize-6 ms-rteForeColor-1"> </span><span class="ms-rteForeColor-1"></span><span class="ms-rteForeColor-1"></span>
          <div class="ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox" contenteditable="false">
    <div class="ms-rtestate-notify  ms-rtestate-read 2c2e53d8-9808-4d04-af98-c2b2e5b4d7ce" id="div_2c2e53d8-9808-4d04-af98-c2b2e5b4d7ce" unselectable="on">
  </div>
  <div id="vid_2c2e53d8-9808-4d04-af98-c2b2e5b4d7ce" unselectable="on" style="display: none;">
  </div>
     </div></marquee>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the container having morquee tag?
You might need that and depends on that you can set colour with the help of CSS class.

Comment: Try removing this css class `ms-rteForeColor-1` and `ms-rteThemeForeColor-9-5` from all places where it is used, to not get colors from SharePoint theme branding

Comment: Remember, ``marquee`` is a deprecated tag, once introduced in IE, never became a standard. So your mileage may vary on other browers.

Comment: Have you thought about using something more modern? Something like pulling in your items via the REST API and adding css animation to them?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing color tag in marquee with !importance to override color in items.

```
<marquee scrolldelay="30" direction="left" scrollamount="8" style="width: 1350px; height: 396px;color:red !important">
```

Comment: i tried this already but dint work. is there any way to change the font color for this particular web part

Comment: can you share the html rendered after displaying webpart